# Regex pattern nested inside other pattern

Tags: regex

I have a string with some embeded variables in it, and I need to extract the names of those variables. I'm not versed in regular expressions and I'm having trouble getting this to work.

Here's and example of how the string looks:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {% #varName1 %}, consectetur adipisicing #non_var elit, sed
>
> {% #varName2|prop1 %} do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
>
> {% identifier #varName3|prop2 %}. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

Variable names are prefixed with `#` and are placed inside the these delimiters `{%` and `%}`. Using this expression I can match the variable names:

```
(?<=#)(.*?)(?=[\s\|])
```

However this matches also `#non_var` which is not inside the delimiters and is not a valid variable.

I've also tried this:

```
(?<={% )(#(.*?)[^\s\|])(?= %})
```

But that only matches `#varName1` and `#varName2|prop1` (for which I don't need the `prop1` part). The expected result is to match:

`varName1`, `varName2` and `varName3`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned which language/application is in use, I'll give a general use case; I myself have tried it in Notepad++ with success.

You could use the regex:

```
(\{%[^#]*#)([\w]*)(.*?%\})
```

Here `varname` may consist of any length of alphabets, digits and underscores. If you want to enforce the condition that the first character of the variable name may not be a digit, use:

```
(\{%[^#]*#)([a-z_][\w]*)(.*?%\})
```

This will recognize everything between and including `{%` and `%}`. Now you can use a back reference to the second matched sub-expresion (`$2` in Notepad++; `\2` in many programming languages) to get `varnames`.

For your input text,

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet {% #varName1 %}, consectetur adipisicing #non_var elit, sed {% #varName2|prop1 %} do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua {% identifier #varName3|prop2 %}. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

my search and replace gave me:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet varName1, consectetur adipisicing #non_var elit, sed varName2 do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua varName3. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

Comment: Did a little tweaking and this `(?:\{%[^#]*#)([\w]*)(?:.*?%\})` captures only the variable names. Thanks again

Comment: @Bogdan: Lookaheads.. Good thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I think this is right:

```
(?<=\{%.*#)[\w|]+(?=.*%\})
```